# Searching and scraping Hacker News - Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping, mechanize

I'm working on a rails app that searches and scrapes Reddit and Twitter to return relevant headlines for a query. I'm trying to add Hacker News as an additional source. I was initially going to use Mechanize to interact with the HackerNews search page, but I can't seem to make any progress. My first idea was to get this working in Ruby so I can better understand how to build into my rails app. Basically I'd like to fetch the search result titles and urls. Here's what I have so far, but I'm not sure how to proceed with doing this in Ruby.

```
    require 'mechanize'

    agent = Mechanize.new
    mech_page = agent.get('https://hn.algolia.com/')
    form = mech_page.forms.first
    form['q']= "ruby"
    agent.submit(form)
```

Any ideas or direction would be very much appreciated!

UPDATE 7:30pm EST=====================================================

This seems to return what I'm looking for when scraping google:

```
    require 'mechanize'

    mechanize = Mechanize.new
    url = "https://www.google.com"
    page = mechanize.get(url)
    form = page.forms.first
    form['q'] = 'Ruby'
    page = form.submit
    page.search('.r a').each do |link|
      puts link.text.strip
    end
```

and returns:

```
    "Ruby Programming Language"
    "Ruby (programming language) - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia"
    "Ruby on Rails"
    "Ruby | Codecademy"
    "Ruby-Doc.org: Documenting the Ruby Language"
    "RubyInstaller for Windows"
    "Downloads - RubyInstaller"
    "Images for Ruby"
    "Learn Ruby with the Neo Ruby Koans"
    "Programming Ruby: The Pragmatic Programmer's ... - Ruby-Doc.org"
```

But with similar code scraping https://hn.algolia.com/...

```
    require 'mechanize'

    mechanize = Mechanize.new
    url = "https://hn.algolia.com/"
    page = mechanize.get(url)
    form = page.forms.first
    form['q'] = 'Ruby'
    page = form.submit
    page.search('.title a').each do |link|
      puts link.text.strip
    end
```

...nothing is returned, even though results are shown on the actual page after running the query. Any idea on how I can scrape the results? Inspecting the element reveals the class name as "title" which is the parent to the 'a' tag

Comment: You'll need to narrow that down to a specific question.

Comment: what do you expect to see? What did you get instead?

Comment: updated above. Thank you for your insight.

Comment: Any ideas pertaining to my update above?

Answer (score 1):

You should rather give a try to the API (http://hn.algolia.com/api) or use the RSS (http://news.ycombinator.com/rss & https://news.ycombinator.com/bigrss)

Your code is not working because the hits are loaded in JavaScript. Your should use the API without any HTML parsing, just like that:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'json'
JSON.parse(open("https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search_by_date?query=ruby&tags=story").read)['hits'].map { |h| h['title'] }

["Learning Ruby on Rails – the resources crossroads", "Rubygems dependency API is down", "Sr.  UI   Engineer", "Immutability in Ruby: Part 2", "Immutability in Ruby: Part 1", "A collection of awesome Ruby libraries, tools, frameworks and software", "Elixir vs. Ruby Showdown – Phoenix vs. Rails", "Ask HN: Website to trade programming skills?", "This Kid Made An App That Exposes Sellout Politicians", "Ruby Queue Pop with Timeout", "Exploring Ruby’s Regular Expression Algorithm", "What should you learn together with Ruby on Rails", "25 Great Talks from the Atlanta Ruby Users Group", "What's the best way to do Business Analytics for MongoDB data?", "Ruby on Rails Internship", "Will Ruby on Rails be better for fast deployment than Ruby?", "Ask HN: Making Front End Work Suck Less?", "AngularJS with Ruby on Rails by David Bryant Copeland", "Ask HN: Path to become a Product Manager?", "Awesome Ruby"]
```

Comment: Adding more specifics above.

Comment: I'm not sure how to parse the data returned by the API search url. For instance, to query 'ruby' I would use the url https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search_by_date?query=ruby, but I would replace ruby with an interpolating variable defined by my query parameter. Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
page = form.submit
```

now inspect page, do it from irb or pry and figure out how to get what you want

Comment: Clarified question above.

Comment: Inspect page. Check page.uri to make sure all the redirects happened. Check page.body to make sure you're seeing what you expect.